# Can't run pytest\requests tests for Flask app inside Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-requests, pytest

My setup -

```
project/
    app.py
    test_hello.py
    test/
    Dockerfile
    requirements.txt
```

app.py body is

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/hello')
def privet():
    return 'hello bob'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

test_hello.py body is

```
import requests


def test_hello():
    session = requests.Session()
    session.trust_env = False
    s = session.get('http://localhost:5000/hello').text
    assert s == 'hello bob'
```

Dockerfile is

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
CMD ["pytest"]
```

When I'm launching test locally on my machine - Everything is OK

But when I'lauching test on Docker container (after building image and running container) - I'm getting error from requests:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /hello (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbcacb07c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:516: ConnectionError
```

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong? Awesome thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So sorry

The problem was in 2 CMD lines usage

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) -

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to `host.docker.internal` (instead of the `127.0.0.1`) when you are in the Docker environment. The special DNS name may be slightly different depending on the Docker version (Windows/MacOS).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540) is a very good answer which explains this issue.